# How to handle division by zero in DataTable.Compute()

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to build a module where customer can create custom formulas and calculate them on the data he has in SQL database.

The customer has access to basic arithmetic operators (+, -, *, /) and aggregate functions (MIN, MAX, AVG, SUM). In addition he is given a set of columns he can perform those operations on, for the sake of the example: (UnitsProduced, ProductionTime, DownTime etc.). With these tools he can construct formulas such as: `SUM(UnitsProduced)/SUM(ProductionTime)`.

After checking that the formula is mathematically correct and contains only valid columns I fetch the data using Stored Procedure from SQL Server into DataTable in C# and then use DataTable.Compute() method on that formula.

The problem is when the aggregate function yields 0. I tried padding the provided formula with IIF condition so that `SUM(UnitsProduced)/SUM(ProductionTime)` becomes `SUM(UnitsProduced)/IIF(SUM(ProductionTime)<>0,SUM(ProductionTime),NULL)` and i would expect to get null as the result but it gives me the error:

> Cannot evaluate. Expression 'System.Data.FunctionNode' is not an aggregate

After doing some research I found that I cannot use aggregate function in a conditional statement. I haven't tried LINQ yet and I don't know if it's going to work.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: To handle it in SQL, you would wrap the divisor with an `NULLIF`.

Comment: @Larnu The thing is I don't always know who is the divisor and making `NULLIF(ProductionTime, 0)` could lead to an error in case where the customer makes a formula: `SUM(ProductionTime+DownTime)`. If ProductionTime is 0 it will become NULL and nullify the result of the formula despite DownTime having a positive value.

Comment: You state above that the user is creating the formula, and you are parsing it, so it seems should be updating the divisor in parsing. If you post your code that does the parsing, I am sure someone will be able to assist there.

Comment: @Larnu Do you mean to parse the formula to become: `SUM(UnitsProduced)/NULLIF(SUM(ProductionTime),0)`? If so then it is not going to work because Compute doesn`t support NULLIF according to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

After some research, me and my colleagues came to an interesting solution.

Basically you need to find all the divisors of the given formula and create a filtering string that will filter out all the data where the divisor is 0. This code also handles aggregation on multiple columns because Comute can't do that.

The code that takes care of zero divisions and aggregation:

```
            DataTable dt = db.GetDataFromStoredProcedure("GetCustomFormulasData", param);
            //Avoid zero division
            List<string> divisors = GetFormulaDivisors(formula);
            string formulaFilter = "";
            foreach (string divisor in divisors)
                formulaFilter += $" and {divisor}<>0 ";
            if(formulaFilter != "")
                formulaFilter = formulaFilter.Remove(0, 5); //remove the 1st " and " 

            //Compute cant handle multiple columns in one aggregate, so we handle it here
            List<string> aggregations = GetFormulaAggregations(formula);
            for (int i = 0; i < aggregations.Count; i++)
            {
                string expr = aggregations[i].Substring(4, aggregations[i].Length - 5);//remove the agg func and last paren 
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn
                {
                    DataType = typeof(float),
                    ColumnName = $"Column{i}",
                    Expression = expr
                };
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
                Regex rgx = new Regex(Regex.Escape(expr));
                string temp = rgx.Replace(aggregations[i], dc.ColumnName);
                rgx = new Regex(Regex.Escape(aggregations[i]));
                formula = rgx.Replace(formula, temp);
                if (formulaFilter != "")
                    formulaFilter = rgx.Replace(formulaFilter, temp);
            }

            return float.Parse(dt.Compute(formula, formulaFilter).ToString());
```

Where GetDataFromStoredProcedure, GetFormulaDivisors, GetFormulaAggregations are inner methods that do as their name suggests.

So for the example of formula `SUM(GoodUnitsProduced+RejectedUnits)/SUM(ProductionTime)`, the DataTable dt will get the Columns: (GoodUnitsProduced, RejectedUnits, ProductionTime) from stored procedure, List divisors will have SUM(ProductionTime) and List aggregations will have: SUM(GoodUnitsProduced+RejectedUnits) and SUM(ProductionTime).

Right before calling the Compute method the DataTable will have two additional columns, one for each aggregate in the formula and filter will have the divisors in it. So `formula = SUM(Column0)/SUM(Column1)` and `formulaFilter = SUM(Column1)<>0` and the problem of zero division is solved.